# MonoTouch: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: - [... tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9940d70

Tags: c#, uitableview, garbage-collection, xamarin.ios, uisearchbar

I understand there are several similar questions already asked and I went through all of them, but none of them solved my problem.

I have a simple `UIViewController` which contains a `UISearchBar` at top and a `UITableView`. This is the basic code:

```
    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();            
        searchBar.TextChanged += delegate {
            tableView.DataSource = new CodeSearchTableViewDataSource(searchBar.Text);
            tableView.ReloadData();
        };
        tableView.DataSource = new CodeSearchTableViewDataSource(searchBar.Text);
    }

public class CodeSearchTableViewDataSource : UITableViewDataSource
{
    static NSString CELL_ID = new NSString("MYID");

    public List<CodeItem> CodesFound { get; set; }

    public CodeSearchTableViewDataSource()
    {
    }
    public CodeSearchTableViewDataSource(string searchText)
    {
        CodesFound = CodeSearch.Instance.Find(searchText);          
    }
    public override int RowsInSection (UITableView tableView, int section)
    {
        return CodesFound.Count;
    }
    public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(CELL_ID);
        if (cell == null)
            cell = new UITableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, CELL_ID);
        cell.TextLabel.Text = CodesFound[indexPath.Row].Id + " " + CodesFound[indexPath.Row].Desc;
        return cell;            
    }
}
```

I don't have custom delegate. What I don't understand is that when this view loads up the first time, the table is populated with a valid list. However, after I enter a character in search box, a new list is sent to the table, and it crashes.

Answer (score 1):

There's no (managed) reference to the `cell` you are creating in `GetCell` once it returns from the method. As such the Garbage Collector (GC) can collect it whenever it wants to.

For more details see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7311407/220643) (and its links) for the question on: [Monotouch - UITableview Cell null reference exception](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7311295/220643)

Comment: Poupou: Thank you very much for your response, but I just tried to cache the cells, and it didn't solve the problem - I still get the same exception.

Comment: Not sure (hard to be without a full test case) but I think this is related to fact you're replacing `tableView.DataSource` in the `TextChanged` event. The previous one, not being referenced anymore, can be collected before the `UITableView` has completed it's work with it. To **confirm** this keep a reference to the old `CodeSearchTableViewDataSource` in a field and see if your error goes away.

Comment: Okay, I managed to solve my problem by simply recreating the Controller. I believe this is a MonoTouch bug, but I don't know how to reproduce it.

Comment: poupou: To follow up with your comment...From my testing, GC of cells is definitely not a problem here. Once I got it work, it works with or without caching the cells.

Comment: It will depend on your code. So it will likely be fine (as such) until something needs to callback into the managed code (e.g. if you add a button and `Clicked` event in your cell). Just keep this in mind :)