# Monotouch UITableViewCell AddSubView

Tags: c#, ios, xcode, xamarin.ios, custom-cell

I'm attempting to create a table/grid like view which i can use for displaying large amounts of information.

The way I have attempted to achieve this is by creating a custom cell view. It's basically `UINavigationController`, which i know is incorrect as it needs to be a `UIView` in order to add it to the `UITableViewCell.ContentView.AddSubView(UiView view)`.

It looks like this:

[image]

Then in my table source `GetCell()` i have this.

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    int rowIndex = indexPath.Row;
    Incident _incident = tableData[rowIndex];

    UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(cellID);
    if(cell == null)
        cell = new UITableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, cellID);

    CustomCellView content = new CustomCellView();
    content.SetRef(_incident.Id);
    content.SetDescription(_incident.Description);

    cell.ContentView.Add(content);
    return  cell;
}
```

Its the `cell.ContentView.Add` is where i'm going wrong? I Just need to add the custom view i created in IB to the cells content.

Comment: So where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5365385/220643) will help you using Xcode/InterfaceBuilder NIB files with `UITableViewCell`.

One important thing to remember is that you're (often) **re-using** cells and they will be in the state where you left them.

So if you add (e.g. `Add` or `AddSubview`) and **never** remove views (or subviews...) each time you **reuse** a cell then your memory usage will grow over time (and that can happen very quickly while scrolling a table).

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out myself. I was not inheriting the correct view.